# Grunt and Gulp files not detected by visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the current version if VS Code it should be possible to run grunt or gulp tasks as written here: [Tasks in visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks)

But when i press `F1` and enter "Run Task", then i can only run tasks from the `tasks.json` file. I even used the Gulp file from the Docs.

What am i missing or could this bi a bug?

Answer (score 1):

OK the solution seems to be that the `commad` property in `task.json` must be set to `grunt` or `gulp` respectively. It is strange that this is mentioned later under another topic in the Docs.